# Sticking PDF toolbar viewer with the pdf viewing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, viewer

I've been googling but couldn't find the proper answer. I am viewing pdf report in the browser and the PDF toolbar viewer is stickily shown in firefox (that's what I want) yet Chrome, IE, Safari, the pdf toolbar viewer is shown unless we scroll the mouse to the end of the pdf viewing.

Are we enable to stick the PDF toolbar viewer with our pdf viewing like firefox does, with javascript or jquery?